# How to use ExcelDataReader nuget for creating Excel File and Write

Tags: c#, excel, exceldatareader

can we use ExcelDataReader  for creating excel sheet and writing into excel template. Or suggest any tool for the same

Comment: ExcelDataReader is for _reading_, not writing. If you're looking libs for writing, you can start here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

You can use [EPPLUS](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

However, please be aware that it does not handle .xls files (Excel 97-2003)